# how to write step definition that validates the existence of two elements

Tags: cucumber

How can we write a step definition that validates the existence of two elements in step definition and link it to Basic Functionality Page?

Example: Validate the existence of two types of letters named letter1 and letter2

expecting to see result as two elements displayed